# Is there any functions similar to down_interruptible() for mutexes in kernel development?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mutex, semaphore

In the book *Linux device drivers 3rd edition*, the mutex is implemented by semaphore via `init_MUTEX(sem)`. The newer kernel, such as kernel 3.2.X, however, has removed this function and added the support of mutex.

But when I encounter the codes:

```
if (down_interruptible(&sem))
    return -ERESTARTSYS;
```

I can't ensure that whether there is a counterpart of this method for mutex. In other words, how can I interrupt the waiting on particular mutex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't ensure that whether there is a counterpart of this method for mutex. In other words, how can I interrupt the waiting on particular mutex?

Yes, mutexs are pessimistic locks, which replace semaphores in the newer kernels. If you want to take a interuptable lock using a mutex, use, :

```
lock_interruptable()
```

Refer header file:

```
#include <linux/mutex.h>
```